# Video share on facebook wall using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

Am facing issue with sharing videos on facebook wall. Actually the video is sharing on FB wall but the video is not playing inline.

This is the shared page meta details,

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Staging Derbywire">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://staging.derbywire.com/video/ticker/102">
<meta property="og:title" content="Derbywire mobile market place">
<meta property="og:type" content="video">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://s3.amazonaws.com/derbywire_development/system/attachments/96/original/open-uri20130822-8464-10q2etf?1377170817">
<meta property="og:description" content="Derbywire is a collective space where creatives can sell buy digital content">
<meta property="og:video" content="http://staging.derbywire.com/video/player">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="480">
```

This is the link for that page http://staging.derbywire.com/video/ticker/102

[image]
While validating this page using the following link

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fstaging.derbywire.com%2Fvideo%2Fticker%2F102

[image]

Its not giving any errors, But its not playing the video.

I gave the source video URL as http://staging.derbywire.com/video/player

This page has the video player

[image]

All the configurations are i did correctly. But the video is not playing. But i changed the source as YOUTUBE link then it was working.

Can any one help me out from this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<meta property="og:video" content="http://staging.derbywire.com/video/player" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

You have to give the URL of the actual SWF file that plays the video here – the address you have given (http://staging.derbywire.com/video/player) however delivers a full HTML document. Facebook is not so silly to just embed full HTML documents into their page.

So change that property to the address of a stand-alone SWF file that will play the actual video.

Comment: In this URL (http://staging.derbywire.com/video/player) am using Flow Player How can i addgive the actual SWF file with video URL.
SWF URL => "http://staging.derbywire.com/javascripts/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf
Video URL => "http://s3.amazonaws.com/derbywire_development/system/videos/102/original/gizmo.mp4"
Can you give me the address of a stand-alone SWF file that will play the actual video.

Answer (score 0):

I Found the solution for playing shared Video/Audio in Facebook wall.

- For Videos i gave the meta tag like this

  ```
  <meta property="og:video" content="https://d12zt1n3pd4xhr.cloudfront.net/fp/swf/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf?config={'splash': true, 'clip':{'url': '<%= url %>'},'plugins': {'controls':{'url':'https://d12zt1n3pd4xhr.cloudfront.net/fp/swf/flowplayer.controls-3.2.15.swf','bottom': 20}}}">
  ```
- For Audio i gave the meta tag like this

  ```
  <meta property="og:video" content="https://d12zt1n3pd4xhr.cloudfront.net/fp/swf/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf?config={'clip':{'url': '<%= url %>', 'provider': 'audio'},'plugins': {'audio': {'url': 'https://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer.audio.swf'},'controls':{'url':'https://d12zt1n3pd4xhr.cloudfront.net/fp/swf/flowplayer.controls-3.2.15.swf', 'backgroundColor':'#002200', 'fullscreen': false, 'height': 50, 'autoHide': false}}}">
  ```

If you gave the proper meta tags in your link page facebook automatically play the video/audio.

For HTTPS users, you have to give HTTPS SWF configuration. Otherwise the file wont play inline.